# Equivalent of "Deadbeat Dad" for Mothers

Tags: translation

We're trying to translate something from the Polish language into English that describes a bad mother. Is there an equivalent phrase to "Deadbeat Dad" except for mothers? Whenever I see "Deadbeat" in front of something, it's usually Dad.

How would you describe a bad mom using a different idiom or phrase?

mj

Edit 1: One additional piece of information: the translation from Polish translates into "villainous mother". There is an element of horribleness that is described in Polish.

Comment: People also talk about "[deadbeat moms](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=deadbeat+mom&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)," although as you say this is not as common as the expression "deadbeat dad." What do you mean exactly by "a bad mom" though? "[Deadbeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadbeat_parent)" has more specific connotations of not paying child support.

Comment: Note that "deadbeat dad" makes use of alliteration.  It's not clear that there is an equivalently alliterative term for moms.

Comment: A deadbeat dad is a dad who fails in the traditional role of providing for the family.  Before we can answer we need to know: is the mother failing in her traditional role of nurturing or is she failing to provide.  If she simply isn't around she's called an absentee mom.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a specific one for a mother, and I don't believe there is one.  Deadbeat can apply to a mother too.

These words could work:

> [**sponger**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sponger) - a person who lives off other people by continually taking advantage of their generosity; parasite or scrounger
>
> [**wastrel**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wastrel) - a person who wastes time, money, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, looking for a sufficient answer, I found an article titled ***'Deadbeat Dads vs Miscreant Moms.'***
It seems to be a bit jerry-rigged, but it provides a suitable alliteration, and seems to equate as far as definition goes. Let's compare - 
**Deadbeat**: *A person who tries to evade paying debts.*
**Miscreant**: *A person who behaves badly or in a way that breaks the law.*

Best you are going to get in terms of a direct mutually exclusive gender equivalent. 
Thanks.